# Wallpaper set using python script disappears after shutting down

Tags: python, ctypes

I was trying to automate changing my wallpaper with python and came across this solution.

```
    import ctypes
    
    SPI_SETDESKTOPWALLPAPER=20

    ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_SETDESKTOPWALLPAPER, 0,r'E:\Pictures\DSC_0594.jpg', 0)
```

However, the wallpaper disappears after the pc is shutdown.Is there a way to make sure this doesn't happen.

Comment: There are additional flags (last parameter) needed to set it permanently.  See the duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can copy your file to-

C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

so that your program opens every time when you open your windows.